# Div inside list should be on top of all list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic, html-lists

I have made a dynamic website which creates list of li according to number it gets from database but inside li there is three div, last div class="panelslider".

I want to show on top of all list but its come on top of its on li and behind of other li.

How can i do this ?

Here is my Code :

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>Dynamic</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="panel1" sizcache="0" sizset="19">
            <li sizcache="0" sizset="19"></li>
            <li sizcache="0" sizset="20"></li>
            <li sizcache="0" sizset="21"></li>

            <p class="title"></p>
            <div class="thum"></div>
            <div sizcache="0" sizset="21"></div>
            <div class="panelslider"></div>

            <li sizcache="0" sizset="22"></li>
            <li sizcache="0" sizset="23"></li>
            <li sizcache="0" sizset="24"></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, try:

```
.panelslider{
  z-index:999;
}
```

Or even,

```
.panelslider{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
}
```

Its hard to say without more CSS provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with your code.

You can't show div or any tag inside lists. If you wish do so it would be something below:

```
<ul>
     <li></li>
     <li>do something here </li>
  </ul>
```

And if you need to define something else like div, p, etc then define it out of tag.